# ActionBar.setBackgroundDrawable stretching drawable instead of aspect ratio stretch

Tags: android

I want to set the background of my ActionBar, and have the drawable maintain its aspect ratio until both dimensions are greater than or equals to the width/height of the actionbar.

The default seems to stretch each dimension to fit, so the drawable appears warped. This is how I'm doing it:

```
getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(
    getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.my_image));
```

Is there any way to tell actionbar (like an ImageView) to use the stretching mode I want?

Thanks